# iframe Undo/Redo for execCommand using insertHTML (contenteditable)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, safari, contenteditable

So, currently I am working on a small button that asks the user to type the link for a video and then I am taking that link and making it into an iframe and inserting it into a contenteditable using `document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<iframe width='350' height='551' src='<video_link_entered_by_user>'></iframe>")`. This works great and the video gets embedded into the `contenteditable`.

The only problem is that if I do `Command`+`Z` or press `undo` in `Safari`, the `iframe` won't get undone for some reason. It works in `Firefox`, `Chrome`, `Edge`, and `Opera`, but for some reason I think `safari` doesn't understand how to `undo` it.

Is there any workaround for this other than implementing my own undo/redo stack? I just want to be able to get rid of the iframe when the user chooses to `undo` in safari as well and add it back when the user chooses to `redo`. Please help and thanks in advance.

***EDIT:***

Here's a JS fiddle to demonstrate what I'm talking about. If you run this in any browser except Safari and press undo, it works. But not in Safari.
http://jsfiddle.net/qg41pd3k/9/

Comment: For me undo just reopens the last closed tab.

Comment: execCommand and contentEditable are notoriously inconsistent between browsers, so I would recommend looking into some other solution if possible. But since this question is about the workaround, maybe you could paste some placeholder image in Safari instead? and then replace it for iframe later?

Comment: It seems that Safari can't undo the pasting of iFrames, however they're inserted (although, strangely, you can undo/redo the *deletion* of them). When you manually copy/paste the iFrame into the `contenteditable` field, you can't undo that action, either.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not really supported in Safari. 
Checking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand, the execCommand method returns true/false whether the command is supported/enabled or not. In Safari it always returns false (according to my tests).

I think the only workaround is implementing you own undo/redo stack.

Comment: This is not true. You are doing something wrong then, because it doesn't always return false. It also doesn't return false even when you try to undo the frame. It returns true but doesn't do anything. You're probably not running the `document.execCommand` from inside a contenteditable. Did you try my fiddle?

Comment: It seems that `insertHTML` breaks undo/redo history in your case.
If you use `insertText` instead it will work.

Maybe it's just not supported for now.

Comment: @Disfigure Actually, undo/redo works fine with `insertHTML` under most circumstances. Inserting a `div` instead of an iFrame, for instance, works without a hitch in Safari.

Comment: @aaplmath that's I meant, of course it does not break with others tags, but for the OP use case, the iframe seems to break the undo/redo history.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little cache solution to emulate the same behavior and make it works on Safari.

- Add video button
- Undo / Redo Buttons
- `ctrl+Z` or `cmd+Z`
- `ctrl+Y` or `cmd+Y`

Hope this sample of code will help you.

Some optimisation can be added like debounce function, and increase the cache limit.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $document = $(document);
    var $editor = $('#editor');
    var $redo = $('#redo');
    var $undo = $('#undo');
    var $addVideo = $('#add-video');

    var CACHE_LIMIT = 1000;
    var cache = [];
    var position = 0;
    var zKeyCode = 90;
    var yKeyCode = 89;
    
    var editorKeydownEventHandler = function (event) {
        var ctrl = (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey);

        if (ctrl && event.keyCode === zKeyCode) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            undo();
        }
        else if (ctrl && event.keyCode === yKeyCode) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            redo();
        }
    };

    var editorInputEventHandler = function (event) {
        if(cache.length >= CACHE_LIMIT) {
            cache = cache.slice(1);
        }

        cache.push($editor.html());
        position++;
    };

    var redoClickEventHandler = function (event) {
        redo();
    };


    var undoClickEventHandler = function (event) {
        undo();
    };

    var addVideoClickEventHandler = function (event) {
        addVideo();
    };

    var redo = () => {
        if(cache[position + 1]) {
            position++;
            $editor.html(cache[position]);
        }
    };

    var undo = () => {
        console.log('undo');
        if(cache[position - 1]) {
            position--;
            $editor.html(cache[position]);
        }
    };

    var addVideo = function () {
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/9P6rdqiybaw' height='100' width='100'></iframe>")
    };

    $document.bind('keydown', editorKeydownEventHandler);
    $editor.bind('input', editorInputEventHandler);
    $redo.click(redoClickEventHandler);
    $undo.click(undoClickEventHandler);
    $addVideo.click(addVideoClickEventHandler);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At culpa exercitationem itaque maxime porro reiciendis repudiandae veniam vero! Alias at doloremque exercitationem fugiat ipsum natus nihil numquam provident sint, voluptatibus.
     </div>
     <button id="add-video">add video</button>
     <button id="undo">undo</button>
     <button id="redo">redo</button>
     <script
             src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
             crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry mate, this is not working. When i try to undo/redo, the iframe still exists in the contenteditable. Thanks for trying to help anyway :)

Comment: Wait let me rephrase that. when i press add video and then press undo, it does not work. However, if i add the video, then delete it and then press undo, it does insert the video back into the contenteditable. So, it's not working as expected I would say. Cheers!